# Weighted matroid intersection algorithm

Tags: algorithms, matroid-theory

From *Combinatorial Optimization, Theory and Algorithms*, Sixth Edition, 2018, by Bernhard Korte and Jens Vygen:

```
13.7 Weighted Matroid Intersection
…
WEIGHTED MATROID INTERSECTION ALGORITHM

Input: Two matroids (E, F1) and (E, F2), given by independence oracles.
       Weights c : E → R.
Output: A set X ∈ F1 ∩ F2 of maximum weight.

① Set k := 0 and X0 := ∅. Set c1(e) := c(e) and c2(e) := 0 for all e ∈ E.

② For each y ∈ E \ Xk and i ∈ {1, 2} do: Compute
    Ci(Xk , y) := {x ∈ Xk ∪ {y} : Xk ∪ {y} ∉ Fi, (Xk ∪ {y}) \ {x} ∈ Fi}.

③ Compute
    A(1) := {(x, y) : y ∈ E \ Xk , x ∈ C1(Xk , y) \ {y} },
    A(2) := {(y, x) : y ∈ E \ Xk , x ∈ C2(Xk , y) \ {y} },
    S := { y ∈ E \ Xk : Xk ∪ {y} ∈ F1 },
    T := { y ∈ E \ Xk : Xk ∪ {y} ∈ F2 }.

④ Compute
    m1 := max{c1(y) : y ∈ S},
    m2 := max{c2(y) : y ∈ T },
    S¯ := { y ∈ S : c1(y) = m1 },
    T¯ := { y ∈ T : c2(y) = m2 },
    A¯(1) := {(x, y) ∈ A(1) : c1(x) = c1(y)},
    A¯(2) := {(y, x) ∈ A(2) : c2(x) = c2(y)},
    G¯ := (E, A¯(1) ∪ A¯(2)).

⑤ Apply BFS to compute the set R of vertices reachable from S¯ in G¯ .

⑥ If R ∩ T¯ = ∅ then: Find an S¯-T¯-path P in G¯ with a minimum number
    of edges, set Xk+1 := Xk#V (P) and k := k + 1 and go to ② .

⑦ Compute
    ε1 := min{c1(x) − c1(y) : (x, y) ∈ δ+ A(1)(R)},
    ε2 := min{c2(x) − c2(y) : (y, x) ∈ δ+ A(2)(R)},
    ε3 := min{m1 − c1(y) : y ∈ S \ R},
    ε4 := min{m2 − c2(y) : y ∈ T ∩ R},
    ε := min{ε1, ε2, ε3, ε4}
(where min ∅ := ∞).

⑧ If ε < ∞ then:
    Set c1(x) := c1(x)−ε and c2(x) := c2(x)+ε for all x ∈ R. Go to ④ .
If ε = ∞ then:
    Among X0, X1,..., Xk , let X be the one with maximum weight. Stop.

See Edmonds [1979] and Lawler [1976] for earlier versions of this algorithm.
```

[*I haven't formatted subscripts properly; if that makes it difficult to understand, let me know.*]

Step ② has:

```
For each y ∈ E \ Xk and i ∈ {1, 2} do: Compute
Ci(Xk , y) := {x ∈ Xk ∪ {y} : Xk ∪ {y} ∉ Fi, (Xk ∪ {y}) \ {x} ∈ Fi}.
```

I was trying to understand why {y} is included in the set, and then noticed that the only time that Ci is used is in step ③, where the {y} immediately gets removed:

```
A(1) := {(x, y) : y ∈ E \ Xk , x ∈ C1(Xk , y) \ {y} },
A(2) := {(y, x) : y ∈ E \ Xk , x ∈ C2(Xk , y) \ {y} },
```

In step ②, {y} itself is added to make the C(y) set.
In step ③, {y} is removed from C(y) before using it.

What is the point of complicating the definition of C(y) by adding y, only to remove it whenever C(y) is used?

Am I missing something obvious?

(Corollary question: is there a better algorithm for this?)